# Inserting LiDAR points (from laspy) in GeoDataFrame without using a numpy array?

Tags: python, lidar, numpy, geopandas, laspy

Working with Python 3.6 (Anaconda) under Windows using a laspy fork that works with Python 3 (https://github.com/sethrh/laspy).

I am loading a LAS file to a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame to eventually perform a spatial join (using sjoin) with a polygon layer. I am sure there is a more elegant way to do what I am doing using the kludge below:

```
import numpy as np
from laspy.file import File
from pandas import DataFrame
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import Point

#Read LAS file
inFile = File("s428_7568.las", mode = "r")

#Import LAS into numpy array (X=raw integer value x=scaled float value)
lidar_points = np.array((inFile.x,inFile.y,inFile.z,inFile.intensity,
               inFile.raw_classification,inFile.scan_angle_rank)).transpose()

#Transform to pandas DataFrame
lidar_df=DataFrame(lidar_points)

#Transform to geopandas GeoDataFrame
crs = None
geometry = [Point(xyz) for xyz in zip(inFile.x,inFile.y,inFile.z)]
lidar_geodf = GeoDataFrame(lidar_df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
lidar_geodf.crs = {'init' :'epsg:2959'} # set correct spatial reference
```

So, is there a better way, more efficient, more pythonesque way of injecting the .las file points (from laspy) to the GeoPandas dataframe without passing through a numpy array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, is there a better way, more efficient, more pythonesque way of injecting the .las file points (from laspy) to the GeoPandas dataframe without passing through a numpy array?

No, and I'm not sure why you think this is the least efficient way to go. laspy is underneath the covers making a memoryview to the data and the Numpy array is a wrapper over that. There isn't much copying going on at all. You could provide more background on why you think this is the bottleneck.

Note that the latest [1.5.0 laspy release](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/laspy) has included Seth's and other's patches to be compatible with Python 3.5/3.6.

Comment: I am a new to programming in Python so just wanted to ensure I was starting off correctly. Thanks for your insight! And yes, I saw on Git about version 1.5 which is great news as well.

Comment: I am not sure that the list comprehension turning xyz coordinates to points is really efficient. This seems to be a bootleneck in my current, similar code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this method was available in older versions of Geopandas, but this part

```
#Transform to geopandas GeoDataFrame
crs = None
geometry = [Point(xyz) for xyz in zip(inFile.x,inFile.y,inFile.z)]
lidar_geodf = GeoDataFrame(lidar_df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
lidar_geodf.crs = {'init' :'epsg:2959'} # set correct spatial reference
```

could be replaced with the more efficient:

```
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame, points_from_xy

#Transform to geopandas GeoDataFrame
lidar_geodf = GeoDataFrame(lidar_df,  geometry=points_from_xy(inFile.x, inFile.y, inFile.z, crs='epsg:2959'))
```

the function `points_from_xy` seems much more efficient than the list comprehension used

Comment: It was not available then, thank you for your post!